# Add more data with faker.js generates liquibase error

Tags: java, jhipster, liquibase, faker

I've generated a monolith sample app with JHipster 6.1.2 and h2 for dev, with a simple entity.
It generates 10 lines of sample data with fakerjs, but if I add one more line in the data.csv file it generates a liquibase error:

```
2019-06-28 21:59:45.991 DEBUG 16399 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.s.config.LiquibaseConfiguration      : Configuring Liquibase
2019-06-28 21:59:46.149  WARN 16399 --- [  paging-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
2019-06-28 21:59:48.395 ERROR 16399 --- [  paging-task-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          config/liquibase/changelog/20190628133935_added_entity_Book.xml::20190628133935-1-data::jhipster was: 8:ee6d55c24ca401dedb5c3a420721517b but is now: 8:cbad83788edd5ca52ce6bbe66744f473


liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          config/liquibase/changelog/20190628133935_added_entity_Book.xml::20190628133935-1-data::jhipster was: 8:ee6d55c24ca401dedb5c3a420721517b but is now: 8:cbad83788edd5ca52ce6bbe66744f473

    at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:276)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:198)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:305)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:119)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-06-28 21:59:48.896 DEBUG 16399 --- [  restartedMain] io.goovy.sampleapp.config.WebConfigurer  : Registering CORS filter
```

Here is the .yo-rc.json:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "io.goovy.sampleapp"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.1.2",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "paging",
    "packageName": "io.goovy.sampleapp",
    "packageFolder": "io/goovy/sampleapp",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "NDljY2EyOGMxZjNiNmEyNzk0ODc2MTM2OWIwZTQwNjY1MDRkYWRkNzdmOTE0N2M1NThlOWUwNzc5MDE0MDIwNWQ2OTI1ODU5NTk3YWQzNzRlMDc5MTQ2NTkyYWY4ZDllMTBhNzEyNDU5NWE4ZTIwNDg2MWMzNmQwNTE4OWE5MDk=",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "darkly",
    "clientThemeVariant": "dark",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": false
  }
}
```

and I've created a simple entity Book:

```
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "clientRootFolder": "",
    "relationships": [],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "name",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "author",
            "fieldType": "String"
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "release",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate"
        }
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20190628133935",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "service": "serviceImpl",
    "entityTableName": "book",
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true,
    "pagination": "pagination"
}
```

Any idea what should be the best practice?

Comment: Reset liquibase checksums or create manually another migration for your data.

Comment: Yes, actually my point is more based on the comment added in the entity xml file which is not clear, I think, on how to easily add more data

For me, it's easier to truncate the table before, and to restart the project.

Maybe, I can add some note somewhere but I don't know where? in the doc, but where?

Comment: and thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: In the README.md or in the doc https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates